# How do I create a VBA Macro that can function when I send to my colleagues?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA code at work for a database which my colleagues and I will use to store data on cases that we are working on. However, when I share my Excel, the macro doesn't automatically work. 
For it to work, my colleagues need to go into "Macros" and then change "Macros in:" to "(name of doc)" instead of being able to use the default setting "All Open Workbooks". 
Is there a way for me to fix my original macro so when i share it with my colleagues the macro can run without the necessity to make adjustments for every input?
This question may be a bit "elementary" in this forum, but would be highly appreciative of any help.
Thanks!

p.s. Please let me know if you need any more information to diagnose this problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
End Sub
Sub Macro1()
'
' basic variable types: strings, integers & longs
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim financing As String
Dim compName As String
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim fortnr As String
Dim lr As Long


    Set ws = Sheets("INPUT")

    financing = ws.Range("B2").Value
    compName = ws.Range("B3").Value
    fortnr = compName & "-" & financing

    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "B") = financing
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "C") = compName
'
'    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = compName & "-" & financing

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets("Template")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Name = compName & "-" & financing
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetVisible

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template (2)").Name = "Template"

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Range("C4").Value = financing
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fortnr).Range("C5").Value = compName

    ws.Cells(lastRow, "D").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$7"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "E").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$15"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "F").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$10"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "G").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$11"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "H").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$12"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "I").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$6"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "J").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$14"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "L").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$19"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "M").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$17"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "N").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$21"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "O").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$22"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "Q").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$25"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "R").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$26"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "S").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$27"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "T").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$28"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "U").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$29"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "V").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$30"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "W").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$31"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "X").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$32"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "K").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$16"
    ws.Cells(lastRow, "P").Formula = "='" & fortnr & "'!$C$20"

    'ws.Cells(lastRow, "D") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B6").Value
    'ws.Cells(lastRow, "E") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B7").Value

    'ws.Cells(lastRow, "D") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B6").Address
    'ws.Cells(lastRow, "E") = Sheets(fortnr).Range("B7").Address

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(lastRow, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & fortnr & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Check"                                  'Anchor: the place where the link will be

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Range("A1"), "", Sheets("INPUT").Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Back to Input-sheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: What does *then change "Macros in:" to " (name of doc)"* mean? Please share your code as it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: You mean that you want to run a macro (automatically) when another user opens your workbook?

Comment: Hi guys,
Sorry, I wasn't too clear. Let me explain in more detail:
I have created a command button function, so I type in two inputs and then click the button and a new worksheet is created, in which I input data which then gets linked back to the initial worksheet. However, when my colleague clicks the command button it wont run. They need to adjust a setting in the Macro for it to work, and I was hoping to make it possible for them to use the command button without any necessary adjustments. I will add my code below

Comment: @IBAndy you can edit your question with new details.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't realize. Still fairly new to this forum (which is a life saver)

Comment: please see [ask] for tips on improving this question :)

Comment: Thanks David, reading it now.

Comment: When your colleague clicks the command button, I'm pretty sure it runs (unless they have macros disabled from security settings, which is *not* what you indicate). The problem is your command button only increments  the value in `Range("A1")`. It doesn't run `Macro1`. And it doesn't on your computer, either, unless there's more code (like a `Worksheet_Change` event) that you're not showing us.

Comment: Hi again David, 
Macro1 works fine for me. When I click the command button a new worksheet is created in which I can input values that are also linked to the initial worksheet. Doesn't seem like a left anything in my code out of my question. The problem when I send this file to my colleagues, they need to go into the developer tab, click "Macros" on the top left of on the worksheet and change the setting "Macros in:" to the name of the document, and then click "run". 
Please let me know if I am still being unclear.

Comment: You must call `Macro1` in `CommandButton1_Click` otherwise `Macro1` will not run if you click the button.

Comment: Hi Peh,
I called Macro1 in CommandButton1_Click, but still doesn't work for my colleagues...

Comment: Are you trying to run a macro from a different workbook? Is that why you require to use All Open Workbooks?

Comment: Hi Dave,
No, the Macro is in the same workbook. The default setting seems to be "All Open Workbooks", but for it to work for my colleagues they need to change it to [name of document] (in this case "Pricing Database-Master")

Comment: Okay, just confused me, as I would usually select "This Workbook". The best button to assign a macro would be from the forms control tool box. Draw the button, then right click on it and select Assign Macro, assign the correct macro to it. Use a better name than Macro1, it  would be easier to find in a macro list.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that was the problem. Working now!